# Header cannot be responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I am trying to make my header responsive but I couldn't manage it. So my header is two part. One phone and email are in the left and some links are on the right.

```css
header .head-contact {
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff6dd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header .container .left {
  font-weight: bold;
}

header .head-contact .container .left a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: #000;
}

header .head-contact .container .left a i {
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

header .container .right {
  color: #000;
  text-align: right;
}

header .container .right span {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:963px) {
  header .head-contact {
    height: 60px;
  }
  header .container .left,
  header .container .right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="head-contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 left">
          <a href="tel:02129252027"><i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone"></i>0000000000</a
                  >
                  <a href="mailto:info@dheder.org.tr"
                    ><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> abc@djfdfkj.com</a
                  >
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 right">
                  <a class="right" href="">ABout</a>
          <span>|</span>
          <a class="right" href="">Contact</a>
          <span>|</span>
          <a class="right" href="">Account</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

So it doesn't fit properly, I don't know what I am doing wrong in media query.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add this CSS rule,

```
header .container>.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

... and `margin-left: auto` on its child element that should be right-aligned, you should get what you want. And remove `text-align: right` from `.right`.

For the mobile version (i.e. in the media query) switch `flex-direction` to `column` and reset all side margins and paddings as below:

```css
header .head-contact {
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff6dd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header .container>.row {
  display: flex;
}

header .container .left {
  font-weight: bold;
}

header .head-contact .container .left a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: #000;
}

header .head-contact .container .left a i {
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

header .container .right {
  color: #000;
  margin-left: auto;
}

header .container .right span {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:963px) {
  header .head-contact {
    height: 60px;
  }
header .container>.row {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
header .container .right {
  color: #000;
  margin-left: 0;
}
header .head-contact .container .left a {
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="head-contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 left">
          <a href="tel:02129252027"><i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone"></i>0000000000</a>
          <a href="mailto:info@dheder.org.tr"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> abc@djfdfkj.com</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 right">
          <a class="right" href="">ABout</a>
          <span>|</span>
          <a class="right" href="">Contact</a>
          <span>|</span>
          <a class="right" href="">Account</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was trying to handle with this via @media.